# How can i set my ApolloServer to open a graphql playground instead of the apollographql sandbox by default?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

My question is how can i set [this graphql playground extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/graphql-playground-for-ch/kjhjcgclphafojaeeickcokfbhlegecd/related?hl=en) as my default playground instead of using the default [sandbox](https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer) when i visited http://hocalhost/port/graphql. Is there any option that i can set during the creation of the `ApolloServer` instance that can configure that?.

```
...
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      validate: false,
      resolvers: [HelloResolver, UserResolver],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ em: orm.em, req, res }),
  });
  await apolloServer.start();
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **GraphQL Playground plugin** and provide it to your **Apollo Server constructor**. [For more info checkout Apollo Docs.](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/#graphql-playground-landing-page)

```js
import {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground
} from "apollo-server-core";

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  ...
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
  ],
});
```